# GCC is non-conforming?

Tags: c, multithreading, c11

I know that very few compilers actually support C11 threads (which is sad, but whatever). The C11 standard demands that an implementation that doesn't support threads defines `__STDC_NO_THREADS__`. Yet this program seems to give an error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef __STDC_NO_THREADS__
    #include <threads.h> //error is here
#endif // __STDC_NO_THREADS__

int main(void)
{
    #ifdef __STDC_NO_THREADS__
        printf("There are no threads");
    #else
        printf("There are threads");
    #endif // __STDC_NO_THREADS__
}

//Error at line 3: fatal error: threads.h: No such file or directory
```

Compiler version is GCC 9.2.0 (Windows 10 x64), with `__STDC_VERSION__` = `201710L` (so it is C17). If you cannot tell, the problem is that my compiler doesn't define either `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` or `<threads.h>`, which doesn't conform to C11. What could the problem be?

Comment: Have you tried to force the compiler to C11 (or C17) mode with `-std=c11`?

Comment: No, I didn't. It worked, but still weird. Is it conforming to define `__STC_VERSION__` as 201710L and not define anything related to threads?

Comment: Good question. I would expect `__STDC_VERSION__` to always correspond to the actual mode the compiler is in, so this does feel like a bug to me.

Comment: I just tried it on godbolt.org but can't reproduce the observed behavior. For GCC 9.2, `__STDC_VERSION__` seems to always correspond to the selected mode (and doesn't exist for `-std=c89`), and `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` is **always** defined as 1 (even in c89 mode). So there's something strange going on with your compiler.

Comment: I think this depends on which std lib you are using, rather than the compiler. If you are using some Mingw64 flavour, then it is using Microsoft Non-standard lib. Whereas godbolt etc likely uses libc.

Comment: @Lundin very good point, didn't think about that. Makes perfect sense, given that OP's platform is Windows 10.

Comment: I think it is using the MS C runtime so you may be right. Just realized a crucial mistake: It **doesn't** work even with `-std=c17`, the `#include` was commented but I didn't see it :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pre-C11 compilers and libraries will not define `__STDC_NO_THREADS__`, nor will post-C11 ones with support for threading. So a correct check needs to look like this:

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L && !defined(__STDC_NO_THREADS__)
  #include <threads.h>
```

Otherwise older versions of the compiler/library will not work. In your case, you seem to be using Mingw under Windows, in which case the non-compliant Microsoft CRT is used (it does not conform to C99 and beyond).

Later versions of gcc using later versions of libc seem to work correctly with the original code.

Please note that gcc is not to be regarded as a conforming implementation unless you compile with `-std=c17 -pedantic-errors`. I don't think it matters in this specific case.

Comment: This is very weird. If I try the same code for the `<stdatomic.h>` header, it works. Not only that, I can even declare `_Atomic` variables and it even has the typedefs for `atomic_int` etc. I cannot test if they are truly atomic or if they are placeholders, because I have no threads. But I don't know why the MS CRT would define atomics but no threads.

Comment: @DarkAtom I think MS did some "cherry picking" of various parts of C99 and C11, at the same time that they upgraded to C++11. Some parts of C11 and C++11 are similar. They did this somewhere around VS 2015. I don't use their compiler so I don't know.

Comment: So is there any other library that I can use except for MSVCRT? I mean, Linux has literally tons of them, why would Windows have only one?

Comment: @DarkAtom I think there's been some projects regarding porting libc to Windows. Maybe if you run Cygwin, not sure. There's also Embarcadero, but they are heavily C++ focused like MS.

Comment: @DarkAtom I think there is some support in MinGW-w64 for using Microsoft's UCRT as the base for the toolchain and headers. It's probably best to treat that as a work in progress for now.